# Image upload error. unable to create directory

Tags: magento-1.8, product, image, admin-panel, upload

I am very new to magento. I have created one magento store, that is working fine in the localhost. But in server it's working fine except product image upload. I can able to create new product but product images are not uploading. I got this error:

> unable to create directory /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/media/tmp/catalog/product/...

Please refer the following screenshot.

[image]

Tried out following:

1. Checked the `/media` folder permission that is in 777
2. Changed the `php_value memory_limit 128M` to `256M` in `.htaccess`
3. GD library is installed
4. Changed attribute scope of small image, large image, thumbnail scope (panel -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage attributes) from stroe view to global
5. Tried this http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.in/2011/09/upload-issue-for-magento-1600.html link.

Still am not get any solution. It wasted my time around 2 days.

Please any one help me.

Comment: is this issue sovled?? What is the solution for this?

Comment: Usually a file permission AND ownership issue. Ownership as the logged in sftp user is not the same as running owner of the web server process. Not sure how a minor PHP upgrade would have fixed the issue, sounds like an server management issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution at 22-Aug-2014.

Problem is PHP version issue, megento  need php 5.2.13 but my server contains php 5.2.12

After updated php version, image upload working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem earlier and I  have solved this.

It was issue `with lot of file in media/temp/catalog/product/s/a directory`
that means `lake of  files on this folder which prevent by the server`

Comment: But there is no file inside that folder (media/temp/catalog/product/s/a).

Comment: how many folder and file in media/temp/catalog/product/??

Comment: Thanks Amit for your quick reply,                                    But there is no file inside that folder (media/temp/catalog/product/s/a). I want to mention one more thing, manually changed the temp directory to var/tmp in lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php. In new temp folder also no file / directory exists. I have chagned the line 91 ('cache_dir' => null to 'cache_dir' => 'var/tmp') and changed permissions too.

Comment: is it works your solution

Comment: Only one folder with the name 's' and it has one sub folder named 'o'. One these two folders are exists.

Comment: I mentioned wrongly in previous comment, the line 91 ('cache_dir' => null to 'cache_dir' => 'var/tmp') is wrong,   actually am changed as following 'cache_dir' => null to 'cache_dir' => 'media/tmp'.

Because when am click the panel->catalog->Manage Products, exception thrown as "Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually" and not showing any products.

After changed that cache_dir, can able to view product list and able to add new product. But my problem is images are not uploading.

Comment: chache_dir => 'var/tmp' no exception thrown but image not uploaded.
chache_dir => 'var/tmp' throwing exception but image not uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised nobody mentioned disk space. Here's how to increase it:

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/manage-disk-space.html#no-space-left

Answer (score 0):

In `magneto 1.9` I solved it **`purging the cache`** from `system/cache management`.
You will be able there to purge 4 kind if caches when I purged them all. the problem is solved.

Answer (score -2):

Go to this file: `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Image.php` and comment these lines:

```
if ($file && $file != 'no_selection' && !$this->_checkMemory($baseDir . '/' . $file)) { 
     $file = null;
```

maybe it works for you. :)

Comment: Never edit the core code. and by never I mean NEVER.

Answer (score -2):

This issue can be resolver making in /var/www

I got the solution for this problem. This problem may have two cause and both are based with the file permission.. 
1. Please check that you have a temp folder in media. Some time its not created in time of installation like was in my case. If yes the create a folder name tmp and also give the permission 777 so mangento code can create sub folders for images. 
2. Also check that you have a folder name with catalog in media folder. And in media folder should be subfolder name category and product and pls give the permissio 777 to all.