# Magento 1.9.3.0 file was not uploaded error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, image, upload

When I upload the product background and click upload pictures, it always prompt, this file was not uploaded error
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image upload error. unable to create directory](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33058/image-upload-error-unable-to-create-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I have been solved this issue with clear `/var/session`, `/var/cache` & `/var/log` folders.